# Jasper report: How to passing params from jrxml to php application using PHPJasperXML Library

Tags: php, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a question about passing params from jasper report design jrxml to php application.
I design my report with the query below:

```
SELECT
student.`STUDENT_ID` AS student_STUDENT_ID,
student.`STUDENT_NAME` AS student_STUDENT_NAME,
student.`MARK` AS student_MARK,
student.`CLASS_ID` AS student_CLASS_ID
FROM
`student` student
WHERE
(CLASS_ID = $P{class_id} or $P{class_id} = '')
AND $P!{myParamSQL}
```

All my params are: class_id, student_id and myParamSQL
The default value of myParamSQL is:

```
($P{student_name}==null ? "1=1" : "STUDENT_NAME = '" + $P{student_name} + "'")
```

I preview this report from ireport tool and everything seem ok. But i don't know how to pass those params to my php application.
I try to use this code below but the result is "No data Found"

```
$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("class_id"=>"'" .'C001'. "'","student_name"=>"'" .'Jonny'."'");
```

If my query not use $P!{} syntax then my php app can run the report, but i need to use $P!{}

Here is all my php codes:

```
<?php
/* 
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
include_once('jasperclass/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
include_once("jasperclass/PHPJasperXML.inc.php");   
include_once ('setting.php');

$p1 = 'C001';
$p2 = 'Jonny';

$PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML();
//$PHPJasperXML->debugsql=true; 
$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("class_id"=>"'" .$p1. "'","student_name"=>"'" .$p2."'"); 

$PHPJasperXML->load_xml_file("report1.jrxml");    
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db);
$PHPJasperXML->outpage("I");    //page output method I:standard output  D:Download file  

?>
```

Can you help me with a fix for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the actual query on iReport for something like:

```
SELECT student.`STUDENT_ID` AS student_STUDENT_ID,
student.`STUDENT_NAME` AS student_STUDENT_NAME,
student.`MARK` AS student_MARK,
student.`CLASS_ID` AS student_CLASS_ID

FROM `student` student

WHERE (CLASS_ID = $P{class_id} or $P{class_id} = '')
AND STUDENT_NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', $P{student_name}, '%')
```

Using this way, your query would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this.

PHP:

```
$xml =  simplexml_load_file("kartuTapir.jrxml");
$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("kd_pasien"=>"'".$id."'",
    "puskesmas"=>$_GET['puskesmas']);

$PHPJasperXML->xml_dismantle($xml);
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db);
$PHPJasperXML->outpage("I"); //page output method I:standard output  D:Download file    F:Save to Local File
```

JRXML to register parameters:

```
<parameter name="kd_pasien" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="puskesmas" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

JRXML to display parameters:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="10" y="25" width="400" height="11" uuid="d1ad6a10-be7f-4579-81ce-9d4b02a7135e"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
        <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{puskesmas}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score -2):

pass parameters in different lines then problem might get solved please check

Comment: To make this answer more complete, consider posting a code snippet or OPs complete code with you advice applied. This is an old question that I'm sure OP has moved on from and so is not likely to mark as an answer. Therefor you need to state your claim why this solution works and is more superior to the previous answers. Sounds like you are not even sure it will work, in that case this would have been better as a comment rather than an answer